# More than one timer on a page at a time

Tags: javascript, timer

Okay I am wondering how I get two countdown timers on the one page?

```
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
   window.onload=function() {
   setInterval("<?php
$array = count($settime);
for ($i = 0; $i < $array; $i++) {
    $thitime = explode(":", $settime[$i]);
    echo "timeleft(" . $thitime[1] . ", " . $thitime[0] . "); ";
}
?>", 1000);
   }
   function timeleft(string, id)
   {
      var xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
      if(xmlhttp==null) { alert("Sorry, Your browser doesnt support HTTP Requests");
      return;
      }
      var elem = "time" + id;
      var load = "time_left.php?string=" + string;
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", load, true); 
      xmlhttp.send(null);
   }
   function GetXmlHttpObject() {
   var xmlhttp=null;
   try {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
        catch (e) {
                   try {
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                       }
                        catch (e) {
                                   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                  }
                   }
   return xmlhttp;
   }
   </script>
```

The page I am trying to run the two timers off is only loading one of the timers, I have tried multiple things to try and fix the issue, and can't seem to figure out what it is that is wrong with it..
I even tried making two different timer scripts and that didn't work..

Here is the complete code of the page I want to run the two timers on..

```
    <?php
/*------------includes--------------*/
include('./includes/connections.php');
include('./includes/brain_file.php');
include('./includes/style_top.php');
/*------------includes--------------*/
if ($pl['my_tuts_on'] == 'yes') {

    echo "<tr bgcolor=#E6E6E6><td>
             Here you can view all the inmates currently in jail. You may attempt to bust/bail them, Bailing them costs a fee, Busting them uses 10 energy and is not a garantee you will bust them, Just be carefull not to get caught and end up in jail yourself. 
             </td></td></tr></table></center><hr/ width=95%>";
}

echo "<center><main>Jail</main><hr width='95%'/>";



if ($pl['my_hosp'] > gmtime()) {
    echo "Sorry this page is not viewable while in hospital!<hr width='85%'/>";
    include('./includes/style_bottom.php');
    exit();
}
$_GET['page'] = abs(intval($_GET['page']));
$min          = ($_GET['page'] > '1') ? (($_GET['page'] - 1) * 25) : $min = 0;
$q_ry         = array();
$q_ry         = "SELECT `playerid` FROM `members`
            WHERE `my_jail` > '" . mysql_real_escape_string(gmtime()) . "'";
$tot          = array();
$tot          = mysql_query($q_ry);

if ($joh['my_jail'] > gmtime()) {
    $settime[] = $pl['playerid'] . ":" . $pl['my_jail'];
    echo "<br><font size=2><b>", stripslashes($pl['jail_reason']), "</b>
          <br>You will be in jail for another <span id = 'time" . $pl['playerid'] . "'><b>" . gettimeleft($pl['my_jail']) . "</b></span> yet!</font><br><br><hr width='85%'>";
}
?>
   <script type = 'text/javascript'>
   window.onload=function() {
   setInterval("<?php
$array = count($settime);
for ($i = 0; $i < $array; $i++) {
    $thitime = explode(":", $settime[$i]);
    echo "timeleft(" . $thitime[1] . ", " . $thitime[0] . "); ";
}
?>", 1000);
   }
   function timeleft(string, id)
   {
      var xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
      if(xmlhttp==null) { alert("Sorry, Your browser doesnt support HTTP Requests");
      return;
      }
      var elem = "time" + id;
      var load = "time_left.php?string=" + string;
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", load, true); 
      xmlhttp.send(null);
   }
   function GetXmlHttpObject() {
   var xmlhttp=null;
   try {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
        catch (e) {
                   try {
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                       }
                        catch (e) {
                                   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                  }
                   }
   return xmlhttp;
   }
   </script>
   <?php

if ($pl['my_jail'] > gmtime()) {
    echo "<b>&gt;<a href='bust.php'>Try and escape for " . abs(intval($pl['my_maxnerve'] / 2)) . " nerve</a></b>
          <hr width='85%'>";
}

echo "<b></b> ";
if (mysql_num_rows($tot) <= '25') {
    echo "";
} else {
    if ($_GET['page'] > '1') {
        echo "<a href='jail.php?page=" . ($_GET['page'] - 1) . "'>&lt;&lt;</a> ";
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < (mysql_num_rows($tot) / 25); $i++) {
        echo "<a href='jail.php?page=" . ($i + 1) . "'>";
        if (($i + 1) == $_GET['page']) {
            echo "<b>" . ($i + 1) . "</b>";
        } else {
            echo "<font color = '#999999'>" . ($i + 1) . "</font>";
        }
        echo "</a> ";
    }
    if ($_GET['page'] < $i) {
        echo " <a href='jail.php?page=" . ($_GET['page'] + 1) . "'>&gt;&gt;</a>";
        exit();
    }
}


echo "<table class='sidebarLink' border='0' width=95% class='rounded'><tr bgcolor=#151515>
         <td height='20'><font color = '#FFFFFF'><b>ID#</b></font></td>
         <td height='20'><font color = '#FFFFFF'><b>Player</b></font></td>
         <td width=25%><font color = '#FFFFFF'><b>Time</b></font></td>
         <td height='20'><font color = '#FFFFFF'><b>Level</b></font></td>
         <td height='20'><font color = '#FFFFFF'><b>Reason</b></font></td>
         <td height='20'><font color = '#FFFFFF'><b>Release</b></font></td></tr>";
$num = 0;

$q_ry = array();
$q_ry = "SELECT `playerid`,`playername`,`my_level`,`jail_offer`,`my_jail`,`jail_reason` 
                  FROM `members` 
                  WHERE `my_jail` > '" . mysql_real_escape_string(gmtime()) . "'
                  ORDER BY `my_jail` DESC
                  LIMIT $min,25";
$hopl = array();
$hopl = mysql_query($q_ry);
if (mysql_num_rows($hopl)) {
    $hp = array();
    while ($hp = mysql_fetch_array($hopl)) {
        $num++;
        if ($num % 2) {
            $color = "#E6E6E6";
        } else {
            $color = "#E6E6E6";
        }
        $q_ry       = array();
        $q_ry       = "SELECT `my_bustreward` 
                  FROM `members_extra` 
                  WHERE `playerid` = '" . $hp['playerid'] . "'";
        $du         = array();
        $du         = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($q_ry));
        $settime[] = $hp['playerid'] . ":" . $hp['my_jail'];

        echo "<tr bgcolor=#E6E6E6>
            <td><a href = 'messages.php?action=send&XID=" . $hp['playerid'] . "'>" . $hp['playerid'] . "</a></td>
            <td><a href = 'profile.php?XID=" . $hp['playerid'] . "'>" . htmlentities($hp['playername']) . "</a></td>
            <td><span id = 'time" . $hp['playerid'] . "'><b>" . gettimeleft($hp['my_jail']) . "</b></span></td>
            <td>" . $hp['my_level'] . "</td>
            <td>" . stripslashes($hp['jail_reason']) . "</td>
            <td>[<a href='release.php?action=bail&XID=" . $hp['playerid'] . "'>Bail</a>] 
                [<a href='release.php?action=bust&XID=" . $hp['playerid'] . "'>Bust</a>]</td></tr>";

    }
} else {
    echo "<tr>
               <td colspan = '7' align = 'center'>
               You walk into the jail to tease some inmates, but there are no inmates to tease!
               </td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>
               <hr width = '95%'>";
if ($pl['my_jail'] > gmtime() || $pl['am_i_staff'] > 4) {
    if ($pl['am_i_staff'] > 4) {
        echo '<table width="95%" align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
        <b>Clear the current shoutbox.</b>
        <form method="post" action="#"><tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="clear"></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="middle" align="center"><input class="hospchat" type="submit" value="Clear ALL Shouts"></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr></form></table><br />';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
        if ($pl['am_i_staff'] < 5) {
            print "Sorry, staff only. <a href=jail.php>> back</a>.";
            exit();
        } else {
            mysql_query("TRUNCATE table `jailshoutsbox`");
            print "All of the jail shouts have been <b>cleared</b> <a href=jail.php>> back</a>.";
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['shout'])) {
        if ($pl['lastShoutj'] == date("i") && $pl['am_i_staff'] < 5 && $pl['my_dondays'] < 1) {
            echo "<div style='background: #DFDFDF;' width='85%'>Sorry, non donators can only post once per minute. <br /> <a href=jail.php> > back</a></div><br />";
            exit();
        }
        if ($pl['my_jail'] <= 0 && $pl['am_i_staff'] < 5) {
            echo "You are not in the jail. <a href=jail.php>> Back</a>";
            exit();
        }
        echo "<div style='background: #E6E6E6;' width='85%'>You've shouted<br /><a href=jail.php>Refresh</a></div><br />";

        $_POST['shout'] = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['shout']));

        $not            = array(
            "'",
            "/",
            "<",
            ">",
            ";"
        );
        $_POST['shout'] = str_replace($not, "", $_POST['shout']);


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `jailshoutsbox` VALUES ('NULL', {$_SESSION['playerid']}, '{$_POST['shout']}', " . date("d") . ")");
    }


    echo '  <hr width=95% /> Post a message on the shoutbox.
        <table width="95%" align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
        <form method="post" action="#"><tr>
        <td>Your Message: (max 155) </td>
        <td><input class="hospchat" type="text" name="shout" maxlength="155"></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="middle" align="center"><input class="hospchat" type="submit" value="Shout"></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr></form></table><br /><table width="95%" style=text-align:left class="table2" border="0" cellspacing="2">
        <tr bgcolor="#151515" style="font-style:bold; text-align:center;"><td style="font-style:bold;" width=55%><b><font color="#FFFFFF">Posted By:</b></td><td style="font-style:bold;" width="44%"><b><font color="#FFFFFF">Messsage:</b></td></tr>
        ';

    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `jailshoutsbox` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 10");
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
        $num9  = $num9 + 1;
        $odd9  = "#CCCCCC";
        $even9 = "#e3e3e3";
        if ($num9 % 2) {
            $color9 = "$even9";
        } else {
            $color9 = "$odd9";
        }
        if ($r['User'] == 1) {
            $r['Shout'] = "<font color='blue'>" . $r['Shout'] . "</font>";
        }
        $user = mysql_query("SELECT `playername` FROM `members` WHERE `playerid`={$r['User']}");
        while ($user1 = mysql_fetch_array($user))
            $player = ($r['User'] == 0) ? "SYSTEM" : "<a href='profile.php?XID={$r['User']}'>[{$r['User']}] {$user1['playername']}</a>";
        echo "<tr height='50px' bgcolor=#E6E6E6><td>$player</td><td style='text-align:center;'>{$r['Shout']}</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}


include('./includes/style_bottom.php');
?>
```

And here is the gettimeleft function.

```
function gettimeleft($tl) {
                  if($tl <= time()) { $release = "0 Seconds"; }
                  else
                  {
                  $mins = floor(($tl - time()) / 60);
                  $hours = floor($mins / 60);
                  $mins -= $hours * 60;
                  $days = floor($hours / 24);
                  $hours -= $days * 24;
                  $months = floor($days / 31);
                  $days -= $months * 31;
                  $weeks = floor($days / 7);
                  $days -= $weeks * 7;
                  $timeleft = ($tl - time());
                  $secs = round($timeleft%60);
                              if ($months > 0)//MONTHS
                                 {
                                  $release .= " $months Month" . ($months > 1 ? "s" : "");
                                 }
                              if ($weeks > 0)//WEEKS
                                 {
                              if ($months > 0)
                                 {
                                  $release .= ",";
                                 }
                                  $release .= " $weeks Week" . ($weeks > 1 ? "s" : "");
                                 }
                              if ($days > 0)//DAYS
                                 {
                              if ($months > 0 ||$weeks > 0)
                                 {
                                  $release .= ",";
                                 }
                                  $release .= " $days Day" . ($days > 1 ? "s" : "");
                                 }
                              if ($hours > 0)//HOURS
                                 {
                              if ($months > 0 ||$weeks > 0 || $days > 0)
                                 {
                                  $release .= ",";
                                 }
                                  $release .= " $hours Hour" . ($hours > 1 ? "s" : "");
                                 }
                              if ($mins > 0)//MINUTES
                                 {
                              if ($months > 0 ||$weeks > 0 || $days > 0 || $hours > 0)
                                 {
                                  $release .= ",";
                                 }
                                  $release .= " $mins Minute" . ($mins > 1 ? "s" : "");
                                 }
                              if($secs > 0)//SECONDS
                              {
                                  if($release != "")
                                  {
                                    $release .= " and";
                                  }
                                  $release .= " $secs Second" . ($secs > 1 ? "s" : "");
                              }
                              }
                       return $release;
                   }
```

Is anyone please able to help me out with this?

Comment: Why are you tying your timer with an AJAX request back to the server and PHP?  Can you just have a timer running client-side/in the browser in JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest with you, I didn't code the timer

Comment: You timer, on client side, is trying run the php code, which must be evaluated on server side. It will never work. It must be completely rewriten using different approach.

Comment: I am still needing assistance with this please someone?

Comment: Someone please I really want to get this working